# Need help creating subdirectories to store files with dates in them

Tags: bash, shell-script, rhel

New to this forum, however not new to RHEL or scripting. However this one is a bit annoying me. I have the following files:

```
2019-05-01-00.34.00.msg 
2019-05-02-00.36.00.msg
2019-06-14-01.38.00.msg
```

I want to store them in directories like this:

```
/2019/05/01/<Filename>
/2019/05/02/<Filename>
/2019/06/14/<Filename>
```

I would like to keep the current file name as well when placing them in the directories. Also, I would like to do this with bash.

Any thoughts?

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://askubuntu.com/q/1181280/693277).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop over the names, split the name on `-`, then `mkdir -p` to create the directories if they don't exist, and finally move. Something like this:

```
for file in *msg; do 
    IFS="-" read -r year month day rest  <<< "$file"
    dir="$year/$month/$day/" 
    mkdir -p -- "$dir"
    mv -- "$file" "$dir"
done
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! Awesome. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly easy with the perl rename tool (**NOT** the rename tool from the util-linux package). e.g.

Setup:

```
$ touch 2019-05-01-00.34.00.msg 2019-05-02-00.36.00.msg 2019-06-14-01.38.00.msg
$ ls -l
total 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 Oct 16 20:56 2019-05-01-00.34.00.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 Oct 16 20:56 2019-05-02-00.36.00.msg
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 Oct 16 20:56 2019-06-14-01.38.00.msg
```

Rename:

```perl
rename  -n '
  use File::Path qw(make_path);

  if (-f $_ && m/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-/) {
    my ($y,$m,$d,$f) = split /-/,$_,4;
    make_path("$y/$m/$d");
    $_ = "$y/$m/$d/$f";
  }' *.msg
```

This script starts by ignoring filenames that aren't regular files (`-f`) or don't match the `^YYYY-MM-DD-` pattern.   This prevents it from making unwanted directories if given garbage input.

It splits the filename into four elements.  The first 3 being the Year, Month, and Day embedded in the filename (`$y`, `$m`, and `$d`), and the 4th being the remainder of the filename (`$f`).

It uses the `make_path()` function from the [File::Path](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Path) standard module to recursively create the directories for `YYYY/`, `YYYY/MM/` and `YYYY/MM/DD/` (similar to the `-p` option of the `mkdir` command).  I could have ran perl's `mkdir()` function three times instead, but I preferred to use `File::Path`.

Then it renames (i.e. moves) the file into the correct directory by setting `$_` equal to `"$y/$m/$d/$f"`

That's the key to how perl `rename` works.  You can use **any** perl code, from a simple `s/foo/bar/` style search-and-replace to scripts much more complicated than the one in this answer.  If the code changes `$_` then that is what the file gets renamed to.  If `$_` isn't changed, it isn't renamed.

NOTE: this one-liner uses `rename`'s `-n` option, so is a **dry-run** only.  To make it actually rename the files, remove the `-n` or change it to `-v` for verbose output, like this:

```
2019-05-01-00.34.00.msg renamed as 2019/05/01/00.34.00.msg
2019-05-02-00.36.00.msg renamed as 2019/05/02/00.36.00.msg
2019-06-14-01.38.00.msg renamed as 2019/06/14/01.38.00.msg
```

BTW, filenames can be provided to the on the command-line (as shown above) or by being piped in to the script (`rename` has a `-0` option so it can accept input from, e.g. `find ... -print0` or anything else that can output a list of NUL-separated filenames).

Finally, `rename` will **not** overwrite existing files unless you tell it to with the `-f` aka `--force` option.

Comment: I'm not sure if RHEL has perl rename packaged.  If not, it's available from [File::Rename](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Rename).   On debian and derivatives, it can be installed with `sudo apt-get install rename`.